# Bootstrap vertical Navigation menu - height on all page?

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulties making the vertical navigation menu to go all the way down to the footer of the page. I tried fiddling with it, but the closest i got is me setting a specific height for the .navbar, and that doesn't help me, since I want it to be responsive.

```
.navbar {

border:  0px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 0px;
background-color: #F2E9E1;
```

}

I am guessing it has something to do with the navbar class.

Here is the entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/u3hf1jht/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by you wanting it to go all the way down to the footer? You could just set the height of the nav to 100% of the page height, if you want it to fill your entire page.

```
ul.nav {
  height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a glance at your snippet of code, it seems you've stacked in navs into navbars, they are two different components in Bootstrap. I'd take another look at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav.

Additionally take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix for positioning your navigation. The actual bootstrap side navigation is a visible example of this in action.